# Django starts putting a slash in front of my static url relative path in 3.1

Tags: django

I had this code that worked ok in 3.0.8

```
<script src="{% static 'js/main.js' %}"></script>
```

with the value in settings:

```
STATIC_URL = (
    "static/"  # /static/ for django web development, static/ for django-bakery build
)
```

when building with bakery it works only if I supply the relative path.

But since 3.1, as per their release notes: `The STATIC_URL and MEDIA_URL settings set to relative paths are now prefixed by the server-provided value of SCRIPT_NAME (or / if not set). This change should not affect settings set to valid URLs or absolute paths.` (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/releases/3.1/#backwards-incompatible-3-1) it puts a / in front of my static url and the build fails.

Any ideas how to avoid it? I use django bakery to bake the site into a single file, no server.

Update: django-bakery will build without errors, but then the index file will have the script like this:

```
<script src="/static/js/main.js"></script>
```

which when you open the index.html, you will receive a 404, `/static/js/main.js` not found. while if you replace it with `static/js/main.js` it will work, since the static folder is in the same folder as the index.

Comment: I'm going to suspect it's a problem with django-bakery. Did you open an issue there? Also, please include the verbose output of the build along with the error information.

Comment: @schillingt it's a semi dead project. so I was hoping to force it in django to not add / before my static path

Comment: I don't think anyone else has encountered this as 3.1 is pretty new. Can you please include the information requested above?